# Regex - greater than specific release version

Tags: regex

I need to make Regex expression which will take into account only versions greater than release version **release/2022.2.1**
So that version should be excluded, along with all previous (2022.1.1, 2021.4.1 etc.)
The first version that I would like to include will be **release/2022.2.2** and any after that.
So I made a regex:

```
^release/2022.[2-9].[2-9]|release/2023.[\d].[\d]
```

And this works!
But this will mean that for every year I need to add `|` and after that years that are coming (`2024, 2025...` etc.)

Obviously this is not an optimal way. How to optimize this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: _How to optimize this?_ - Don't use Regex for that. Regex is to match certain patterns, not to compare values. The next Problem is: What is version 2022.3.11? Or version 22.5.1.2? Years 2023 - 2099 is `20(2[3-9]|[3-9]\d)`

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica I MUST use regex!!! That is my only option! If I need to elaborate why, I can...

Comment: @VeljkoSbbb If you use PC, which you definietely do, you can use bash, PowerShell, cmd, which is still better option than regex. And if you use regex, you MUST use some programming langauage. Just use that language instead.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I'm sure this is just a lack of experience on your part but sometimes OP is using a specific piece of software which provides an input field and a validation field in which your entire validation must be a regex. Vendors don't typically provide a way for an end user to program a callback function and introduce foreign code into their infrastructure. Have patience...

Comment: @MichałTurczyn OK since I need to elaborate... in Jenkins configuration in order to restrict which branches you do not wish to trigger build you can set them statically or through the regex... I do not want to "calculate" if branch should be triggered for build or not when job starts but before that immediately... and Jenkins for this purposes it has field "filter branch name" which accepts only regex expression (no bash or powershell or anything)... I hope now is clear

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thank you very much for your assistance and understanding...

Comment: Is the release format a date, or just random dot-separated digits? Does it always contain precisely 3 numbers separated by dots?

Comment: @jhnc it always contains 3 digits (for example  year 2022, 2nd quartal in the year and 2nd release of the application in that quartal --> 2022.2.2). It's not a format of a date...except of the year... the last figure in practice should not be greater than 9 although theoretically it could be, but we do not need to handle right now

Comment: you can build up a regex incrementally - https://regex101.com/r/iTRcrR/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a regex for all upcoming versions in this format until 2099, take

```
^release\/20(22\.(2\.[2-9]|[3-9]\.\d)|(2[3-9]|[3-9]\d)\.[\d]\.[\d])
```

- `^release\/20` - fix part
- `22\.(2\.[2-9]|[3-9]\.\d)` - all values from 22.2.3 to 22.9.9
- `(2\.[3-9]|[3-9]\d)` - years 23-29 or 30-99
- year 23-99 `\.[\d]\.[\d]` - all versions, .0.0 to .9.9

You can see a more detailed explanation of what's what [here](https://regex101.com/r/j9zm8H/1)

*I still recommend against using regex and use any other language*

Comment: Thanks . the first \ after the "release"  is not required as I think? Or you would suggest it to be there? Thx

Comment: @VeljkoSbbb I just escaped all characters that are recommended (like `. -> \.`. TBO I don't know why `/`needs to be escaped, but regex101 tells me to. Perhaps because in JS you note regular expressions like `regex = /putYourRegexHere/`